# CSS Transition Effect :: Text changing color, but not border

Tags: css, colors, hover, css-transitions, border

I'm trying to apply a transition effect to some icons. The transition works for the font (FontAwesome), but not for the border, and I'm not sure why.

You can see the example [here](http://dev.n2geo.com/), and here is the code:

```
.social-nets-wrapper .social li a {color: rgb(53, 61, 68); font-size: 35px; border-color: #272F37;}

.social-nets-wrapper .social li a::before {background-color: #272f37;}

.social-nets-wrapper .social li a:hover {color: #f7941e; border-color: #f7941e; transition: all 300ms linear 0s;}
```

Comment: Your example seems to work for me in Chrome 43 on OSX. The only change I'd suggest would be moving your `transition: all 300ms linear 0s;` attribute out of `:hover` and onto `.social li a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set in some place of your CSS:

```
.social-nets-wrapper .social li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Then, you need to put:

```
.social-nets-wrapper .social li a:hover {
    color: #F7941E;
    border-color: #F7941E !important; /* add !important to override */
    transition: all 300ms linear 0s;
}
```

Or better, find the wrong declaration an fix it with the right one.

Comment: You nailed it, Imgonzalves. The override worked, but I'll go into the styles and take out that override on the #fff.  Wierd; don't know why that's there… Anyways, thanks so much for your help bro.  Much appreciated.

Comment: File main-style.css, line 910. Easy to find with Firefox inspector, or another like this one.